# Docker support - visual studio 2019 community edition - .net core 3

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

I installed visual studio 2019 community edition, I tried to use docker with "Container Tools in Visual Studio" but I do not find the option to add docker file or docker compose file (.net core 3).

I use this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/overview?view=vs-2019 but I do not find those new menu item (project or solution).

[my menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQl8Q.png)

Comment: **"The Add > Docker Support and Add > Container Orchestrator Support commands are located on the right-click menu (or context menu) of the project node for an ASP.NET Core project in Solution Explorer"** What kind of project did you create?

Comment: Hi, I created an asp.net core web app 3.0. The menu item about Container support command not exsits :(. This is the problem).
At the end I found the problem. I you have my problem and the container support items missing in the menu just download and install the extension from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vs-containers-tools-extensions.

Comment: The option to Add > Docker Support on a project is not displayed while debugging the application. The debugger needs to be stopped to find that option.

Answer (score 0):

Update: The Containers tool window is now included in Visual Studio 2019 starting with version 16.4 Preview 2.